# Deno run - Uncaught PermissionDenied: network access to "0.0.0.0:8000", run again with the --allow-read flag

Tags: deno

Getting error message when I trying to run my first deno program with

```
deno run server.ts
```

> Error  :   Uncaught PermissionDenied: network access to "0.0.0.0:8000", run again with the --allow-read flag

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Deno is secure by default. Therefore, unless you specifically enable it, a deno module has no file, network, or environment access for example. Access to security sensitive areas or functions requires the use of permissions to be granted to a deno process on the command line.

If you are accessing the net you need to pass `--allow-net` flag while running the server and if there are funcnality in your app for reading and wiriting file you need to pass `--allow-read` and `--allow-write` flag.

so,

> deno run --allow-net --allow-read server

Answer (score 3):

Then I run same command with "--allow-read" flag added as below

```
deno run --allow-read flag server.ts
```

and error gone.  Because I was reading a file as deno runs in separate sandbox it will not have access to file system by default. 
we need to agree/provide access to read files by security flags while running scripts.

also all security flags should be written just after like below format

```
$ deno run {any security flag}  {script file name/fullpath }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give permission(s) and you can do this by running the following:

```
deno run --allow-net server.ts
```

Or

```
deno run --allow-read server.ts
```

Or

```
deno run --allow-net --allow-read server.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

Deno is a runtime that is secure by default. This means you need to provide permission explicitly to run privileged actions. Here you are trying to access network to you need to pass the flag `--allow-net` with run command.

```
deno run --allow-net server.ts
```

To make this process of entering multiple flags every time you can create a script and run that script every time.

Like I create a file `run.sh`  at project root level containing run the command with all flags need for running the server.

content if `run.sh`

```
deno run --allow-net --allow-write --allow-read --allow-plugin app.ts
```

then I run this command in the terminal to run the server

```
sh run.sh
```